# XPS 13 Ubuntu Issues

Tags: wireless, drivers, touchpad, xps

I recently installed Ubuntu Gnome 15.04 on my XPS 13 (2015 UHD Screen) laptop as the scaling is a lot better than in Windows.

I have a few issues that I don't know how to address:

1. The WiFi kinda works, it is very slow and drops out every few minutes. I am currently using this driver: https://launchpad.net/ubuntu/trusty/+package/bcmwl-kernel-source Any suggestions for a better driver or solution?
2. Sometimes when typing keys get stuck, for example I will be typing apple and then it starts spamming "eeeeeeeeeeeee..." without me pushing the key down. Pressing another key immediately stops the repeating.
3. I usually use my touchpad with 2 fingers. One for moving the mouse and the other one for clicking. This works perfectly in windows but ubuntu automatically assumes that I am trying to scroll? Is there a good solution to this?

Comment: I suggest asking a separate question for each problem.

Comment: @Pilot6 Does that make my chances for getting an answer higher? If so I will for sure repost them all individually.

Comment: In the StackOverflow Q&A format, it is one question, one answer... it makes it easier for information to be organized and found.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should definitely break these up.

1. There was a bug that was [patched](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/bcmwl/+bug/1424676) for the wifi. I've also gone so far as to get the [DELL ISO Image](https://drive.google.com/file/d/0BxuBIWrIIPFwTjVBZWxIWmx4VGs/view?usp=sharing) and start anew.
2. Dell released a [BIOS Update](http://www.dell.com/support/home/us/en/04/Drivers/DriversDetails?driverId=133FN) to fix the keyboard issue.
3. My touchpad issues were resolved with the BIOS updated, too.

Hope this helps.

Comment: Sadly the wifi still does not work properly. But I have gone as far as ordering a new wifi card, the intel 7265. So this is not a problem anymore. But updating the bios helped with my 2 other issues.